# Google Visualization API load 2 scripts on the same HTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets, google-visualization, google-sheets-api

Hello Im trying to load 2 scripts at the same page but they seem to be overlapping eachother.In the first script im getting a table with a few columns and cells. In the 2nd one im getting just a single cell from the second sheet tab but as i said they overlap eachother and i can see only one at a time. This is my first time using google visualizations and i tried to rename the variables and names but i get the same thing.Is there a way to merge both scripts in one and have the html page load both of them without overlapping. Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body >

<div id="box">

    <script src="js/google-sheets-html.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div id="table">
    </div>

</div>

<div id="box2">

    <script src="js/google-sheets-html2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div id="table2">
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

First Script

```
 google.load('visualization', '1', {
        packages: ['table']
    });
    var visualization;

    function drawVisualization() {
        var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=xxx&output=html&usp=sharing');
        query.setQuery('SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G ,H ,I ORDER BY A DESC Limit 10 label A "Date", B "Agent", C "Client", D "Country", E "Desk", F "Department", G "Method", H "Amount", I "Currency"');
        query.send(handleQueryResponse);
    }


    function handleQueryResponse(response) {
        if (response.isError()) {
            alert('There was a problem with your query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
            return;
        }


        var data = response.getDataTable();
        visualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table'));

        visualization.draw(data, {
            allowHtml: true,
            legend: 'bottom'
        });
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

Second Script

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {
    packages: ['table']
});
var visualization;

function drawVisualization() {
    var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxx/gviz/tq?gid=xxx');
    query.setQuery('SELECT A');
    query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}



function handleQueryResponse(response) {
    if (response.isError()) {
        alert('There was a problem with your query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
    }


    var data = response.getDataTable();
    visualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table2'));

    visualization.draw(data, {
        allowHtml: true,
        legend: 'bottom'
    });
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

combine them into one script.
you only need to load google charts once,
regardless the number of tables / charts being drawn.

see following snippets...

**HTML**

```
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body >

<div id="box">

    <div id="table">
    </div>

</div>

<div id="box2">

    <div id="table2">
    </div>

</div>

  <script src="js/google-sheets-html.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['table']
}).then(function () {
  var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=xxx&output=html&usp=sharing');
  query.setQuery('SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G ,H ,I ORDER BY A DESC Limit 10 label A "Date", B "Agent", C "Client", D "Country", E "Desk", F "Department", G "Method", H "Amount", I "Currency"');
  query.send(function (response) {
    handleQueryResponse(response, 'table');
  });

  var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxx/gviz/tq?gid=xxx');
  query.setQuery('SELECT A');
  query.send(function (response) {
    handleQueryResponse(response, 'table2');
  });

  function handleQueryResponse(response, id) {
    if (response.isError()) {
      alert('There was a problem with your query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
      return;
    }

    var data = response.getDataTable();
    visualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById(id));
    visualization.draw(data, {
      allowHtml: true,
      legend: 'bottom'
    });
  }
});
```